# Evaluating $ \int \frac{\sin x+\cos x}{\sin^4x+\cos^4x}\,\text{d}x$.

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

$$
\int \frac{\sin x+\cos x}{\sin^4x+\cos^4x}\,\text{d}x.
$$
What I have tried:
I tried writing denominator as 
$ \sin^4x+\cos^4x =  1-2\sin^2x\cos^2x $ and $ 2\sin^2x\cos^2x = \frac{1}{2}\sin^2(2x) $
so the integral becomes,
$$
\int\frac{\sin x+\cos x}{1-\frac{\sin^2(2x)}{2}}\,\text{d}x.
$$
Anyone, how do I solve this further?

Comment: Subsitute $x$ with $\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{2}-x$

Comment: use the tan half angle substitution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$\displaystyle I = \int\frac{\sin x+\cos x}{\sin^4x +\cos^4 x}dx = \int\frac{\sin x+\cos x}{1-2\sin^2 x\cos^2 x}dx$$

So we get $$I = 2\int\frac{\sin x+\cos x}{2-(\sin 2x)^2}dx = 2\int\frac{\sin x+\cos x}{\left(\sqrt{2}-\sin 2x\right)\cdot \left(\sqrt{2}+\sin 2x\right)}dx$$

So we get $$I = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int \left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}+\sin 2x}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}-\sin 2x}\right]\cdot (\sin x+\cos x)dx$$

So we get $$I = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int \left[\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{2}-(\sin x-\cos x)^2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}-1+(\sin x-\cos x)^2}\right]\cdot(\sin x+\cos x)dx$$

Now Put $(\sin x-\cos x) =t\;,$ Then $(\sin x+\cos x)dx = dt$

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you instead split the integral as
$$
\int\frac{\sin x+\cos x}{\sin^4x+\cos^4x}\,dx=\int\frac{\sin x}{(1-\cos^2x)^2+\cos^4x}\,dx+\int\frac{\cos x}{\sin^4x+(1-\sin^2x)^2}\,dx,
$$
and then let $u=\cos x$ and $u=\sin x$ in the respective integral. You will get a (somewhat nasty) integral of a rational function, but it is standard.

**Edit**
According to your comment (and I agree), you found out that one get integrals like (after expanding the square)
$$
\int\frac{1}{2u^4-2u^2+1}\,du.
$$
Now, you need to factor the denominator, and this is where things get somewhat nasty. I write down the result (in real terms),
$$
2u^4-2u^2+1=2\Bigl(u^2+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}u+\sqrt{2}/2\Bigr)\Bigl(u^2-\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}u+\sqrt{2}/2\Bigr).
$$
Thus, there are constants $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ such that
$$
\frac{1}{2u^4-2u^2+1}=\frac{Au+B}{u^2+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}u+\sqrt{2}/2}+\frac{Cu+D}{u^2-\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}u+\sqrt{2}/2}.
$$
When that is done, you integrate "as usual". You will typically get logarithms and arctans, depending on what the constants $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ turn out to be.

The solution by juantheron is (as often) a short cut.

Comment: Didn't work mate , gave me 
$ \int \frac{du}{(1-u^2)^2+u^4} $ which is even more complicated to solve !

Comment: Oh no, it is not (conceptually) more complicated, just do partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: Can you guide me for few beginning steps?